# Says command not found: peewee, but then i can import peewee in the python shell

Tags: python, peewee

I installed peewee, but it gave me a couple warnings. Then it says peewee not found, but if I run the python shell, I am able to import peewee. Can someone help me understand how to fix this?

```
(virt1) ☁  ~  pip install peewee
Collecting peewee
/Users/gregwienecke/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
SNIMissingWarning
/Users/gregwienecke/virt_env/virt1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Using cached peewee-2.8.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: peewee
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for peewee ... done
Stored in directory: /Users/gregwienecke/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/01/37/92/e58e351fd9934c1167e2b47229ffe6f2dac238a3c3e76aa198
Successfully built peewee
Installing collected packages: peewee
Successfully installed peewee-2.8.5

(virt1) ☁  ~  peewee --version
zsh: command not found: peewee

(virt1) ☁  ~  which peewee
peewee not found

(virt1) ☁  ~  python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import peewee
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working correctly.  peewee is a python module, there is not a command line application.  It is meant to be used in a python script, just as you did with "import peewee".

Check the peewee examples on github:  [pee wee examples on github](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/tree/master/examples).